# Dynamic content and crawlers

Tags: javascript

Will search engine crawlers index my dynamically loaded content using `Javascript` and API calls? or must I load this content trough server side programming (`PHP`, `ASP`, etc...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has been documented in the [webmasters section](https://developers.google.com/webmasters/ajax-crawling/) of the developer pages on google.

Short answer; no but there are workarounds.